# Why does the Configuration Management module warn not to use in production?

Tags: 7, configuration

In the [Configurations Management](https://drupal.org/project/configuration) module, right before you click the Import button, it warns:

> Importing configurations will write your configurations directly to the activestore. **DO NOT USE THIS ON A PRODUCTION SITE!**

Should I heed this warning? If so, why? What's the point of this module if it shouldn't be used in production?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see module is in Alpha phase. It's available for community testing so that they can able to fix issues and make it stable.

Every project in Drupal.org go through different phases. Please see more above Project Versions [here](https://drupal.org/node/467020).

Alpha version refers to

> These are the first to come out, and are therefore the least stable.
>   Most reported errors are resolved but there are most likely still
>   outstanding known issues, which might include security issues.
>
> These releases are not yet stable enough for production use, but are
>   essential milestones on the way towards the official release. They
>   allow a much wider pool of users to test the latest code and provide
>   feedback before the official stable release. These releases should
>   only be downloaded and used by developers very familiar with Drupal or
>   those wishing to help find bugs in the software.

Since Drupal projects entirely community driven, Module maintainers releases projects for testing. Once they are stable you can use them in Production Environment.

Comment: Ahh... I see that now. That's a bummer. I guess I'll experiment with the Features module instead.

Comment: FWIW, I use Configuration on production sites all the time, never had a problem